# Nginx No Gzip on HTTPS - Only HTTP

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, compression, gzip

I cannot seem to find why this is happening.

Installed Nginx 1.10.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 via apt, enabled gzip in my nginx.conf:

```
##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_vary off;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml image/gif image/jpeg image/png image/tiff image/vnd.wap.wbmp image/x-icon image/x-jng image/x-ms-bmp image/svg+xml image/webp
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 8;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
```

This is working on HTTP but not HTTPS:
https://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjkrb.stream

Are there any configuration options I am missing out for HTTPS gzip?

- Also, I am aware of the vulnerabilities of gzip over https on Nginx, however I am still required to get this working!
- Yes, I have googled and searched Stack Overflow for duplicate issues.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by moving from an Ubuntu build to a CentOS build.

I did not discover what was causing the lack of headers being sent on Ubuntu.